# ImportError: tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nao-robot

I want to integrate `TenserFlow` on `robot nao` . 
I have copied the library `Tensorflow` in a path : `/home/nao` , and i do :

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/nao/tensorflow"
```

but if i import a lib tensorflow ... and run , he print :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In general you cannot install TensorFlow by copying an existing installation to a different computer. The error message `wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64` means that you are trying to load 64-bit code (for the native TensorFlow library) into a 32-bit process. There are two solutions:

1. If you have a `x86_64` processor, install a 64-bit version of Python and install one of the standard Linux releases of TensorFlow using `pip`.
2. If you have a 32-bit processor, you will need to build TensorFlow from source with the appropriate compilation options for the target platform. (Note that TensorFlow on 32-bit platforms is not officially supported, so there is no guarantee that this will work, but at least one person has got TensorFlow to build on a [32-bit ARM platform](http://cudamusing.blogspot.com/2015/11/building-tensorflow-for-jetson-tk1.html).)